# Enum class is not listed in symbol table of binary file? via SPM

Tags: ios, sqlite, frameworks, cannot-find-symbol, swiftpm

When I trying to import third party library shifting from cocoapods to SPM, Symbol not found Error occurs.
I check the binary file and found the enum class in third party library(SQLite.swift) is not listed in symbol-list.
In the case of cocoapods it not happens.

Xcode: 15.0
Library structure:
The Framework-A import SQLite and use the API of it.
App imports both of Framework-A and SQLite as dynamic libraries via SPM.(I add .dynamic in Package.swift of SQLite)
Third party Library(version-0.13.3):
https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift

The link of library seems no problem(otherwise it will give [library no loaded error])  but the some symbol is missing.
In my case, the case in enum class:Connection/location/inMemory is not listed in symbol table.
Does anyone know the reason? Is this the bug of SPM?

---

The Package.swift of SQLite is here:

```
// swift-tools-version:5.3
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "SQLite.swift",
    platforms: [
        .iOS(.v9),
        .macOS(.v10_10),
        .watchOS(.v3),
        .tvOS(.v9)
    ],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "SQLite",
            type: .dynamic,
            targets: ["SQLite"]
        )
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "SQLite",
            dependencies: ["SQLiteObjc"],
            exclude: [
                "Info.plist"
            ]
        ),
        .target(
            name: "SQLiteObjc",
            dependencies: [],
            exclude: [
                "fts3_tokenizer.h"
            ]
        ),
        .testTarget(
            name: "SQLiteTests",
            dependencies: [
                "SQLite"
            ],
            path: "Tests/SQLiteTests",
            exclude: [
                "Info.plist"
            ],
            resources: [
                .copy("fixtures/encrypted-3.x.sqlite"),
                .copy("fixtures/encrypted-4.x.sqlite")
            ]
        )
    ]
)

#if os(Linux)
package.dependencies = [.package(url: "https://github.com/stephencelis/CSQLite.git", from: "0.0.3")]
package.targets = [
    .target(
        name: "SQLite",
        dependencies: [.product(name: "CSQLite", package: "CSQLite")],
        exclude: ["Extensions/FTS4.swift", "Extensions/FTS5.swift"]
    ),
    .testTarget(name: "SQLiteTests", dependencies: ["SQLite"], path: "Tests/SQLiteTests", exclude: [
        "FTSIntegrationTests.swift",
        "FTS4Tests.swift",
        "FTS5Tests.swift"
    ])
]
#endif
```

The runtime error is here:
dyld[2003]: Symbol not found: _$s6SQLite10ConnectionC8LocationO8inMemoryyA2EmFWC
Referenced from: <4B8F1B6D-C959-38BE-84E4-B93DF2BF0DDC> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E6C1C0C2-AC80-4562-AA80-05373206ED9E/MPTDKSampleApp.app/Frameworks/Framework-A.framework/Framework-A
Expected in:      /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E6C1C0C2-AC80-4562-AA80-05373206ED9E/MPTDKSampleApp.app/Frameworks/SQLite.framework/SQLite

The enum class in SQLite is here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWXv2.png)